# Yarn installation error "error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line"

Tags: yarnpkg, pem

I am messing with this error. I can't install packages.

````
warning package.json: No license field
warning No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/commander/-/commander-2.20.0.tgz: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line".```

Thank you for your help.
````

Comment: I solved that. Problem was in yarn config. I have there unnecessary attribute for certificate, the attribute says where the certificate is stored. But for https://registry.yarnpkg.com you need no local PEM certifikate. So I just deleted the attribute and  that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that. Problem was in yarn config. I have there unnecessary attribute for certificate, the attribute says where the certificate is stored. But for registry.yarnpkg.com you need no local PEM certifikate. So I just deleted the attribute and that was it.